# Tabula not ordering extracted table correctly

Tags: python, tabula

[PDF PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C6Y8.png) I extracted one table from PDF using tabula, and the table looks like this:

```
0       |      1       |      2    |      3                |      4
NaN           NaN            NaN         Stages                 NaN
NaN           NaN            NaN         Maximum Average        Treating Minimum Treating 
NaN           NaN            NaN         Ave                    NaN
NaN           step#          Step name   Rate Pressure          Pressure
NaN           NaN            NaN         (bbl/min)              NaN
NaN           NaN            NaN         (bbl/min)psi           (psi)(psi)
1             NaN            Acid        10.8 10.8 5745         5893 5648
2             NaN            PAD         34.4 43.4 9745         10556 3770
3             NaN            0.25 PPA    48.0 51.0 9405         10155 8604 
4             NaN            0.50 PPA    50.5 50.6 8213         8602 8044 
5             NaN            0.75 PPA    50.5 50.6 7754         8150 7247 
6             NaN            1.00 PPA    50.5 50.5 7165         7247 7116 
7             NaN            1.25 PPA    50.5 50.5 7100         7126 7076 
8             NaN            1.50 PPA    50.5 50.5 7036         7076 6992 
9             NaN            Flush       50.4 50.5 7181         7378 3229
```

The original table looks like this:

```
Step #   |   Step Name   |    Average Slurry rate | Mex Slurry rate | Ave Treating pressure |  Max Treating pressure  |  Min Treating Pressure  |
 1              Acid                 10.8              10.8            5745                      5893                       5648
 2              PAD                  34.4               43.4                       9745                      10556                      3770 
 3              .25                  48.0              51.0                9405                        1055                  8604
```

and so on, how can I set the table as close as possible to the original one?

as you can see, the rows with number 1,2,3....... contains in the same row the values that supposed to be under columns.

Comment: without having the PDF, it's going to be difficult to help you. There doesn't seem to be a certain pattern (or at least that I see) that would get you to your expected output

Comment: @MattR would a pic help? just attached it.

Comment: Try `tabula.convert_into(..., stream=False, lattice=True)`

Comment: @stovfl thanks for the answer, still pretty messy, question, as you can see in the pic, is there any other way to get the same format using extraction? weird think is the first table is pretty ok when exported, but not the second one.

Comment: @edgar: `tabule` try to read the second table with the layout of the first table. You have to setup a own crop box for the first table and for the second table. Read [how-to-use-area-option](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py#how-to-use-area-option)